# How to lauch a process with no read / write file privileges

Tags: c#, windows-7

Is there a way to lunch a process in C# with limited read file permissions?

For example: Launch notepad.exe so it is unable to read C:\temp\ but can read C:\abc.

I have code to launch a process in low integrity mode but this only stops the process from writing files. It can still read most files on the disk.

Comment: I've written code that launches a process as a low integrity process windows 7. But processes running in low integrity can still read most files on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

> I have code to launch a process in low integrity mode but this only stops the process from writing files. It can still read most files on the disk.

Yes, and as well it should be able to. The solution here is not to modify the privileges of the *application*, but rather to modify the permissions of the individual *files*.

You can take advantage of discrete user accounts to help you keep things organized. Windows has lots of file security features built in. Ask more questions about that on Server Fault. This is not a programming-related problem, it's an operating system security configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Code Access Security](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/UB_CAS_NET.aspx) appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't taken your example of notepad as a literal example. The only way I know how to accomplish what you're after is to setup a limited account and launch the process as that user. Depending on the requirements of your project this may work but in any environment that you have no control over the user's environment it won't.

Comment: Thanks. I think it can be done. I've read that google chrome launches its sandbox process without read file permissions and that process runs as the logged in user.

Comment: @user1104034: Chrome's sandbox takes advantage of Windows's built-in security model. It uses access tokens, except it uses them in a two-step process where the second token is for a "NULL" user. [This blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/10/new-approach-to-browser-security-google.html) explains more about how it works. Consider updating your question to include more specific information about your requirements if you want someone to provide a more detailed answer. People will be happy to point you in the right direction, but keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.